# Error calling Zend Filter ToInt with PHP 7

Tags: php, zend-framework, filter, zend-framework2, php-7

I have the following Model class:

```
<?php
namespace Tropa\Model;

use Zend\InputFilter\Factory as InputFactory;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareInterface;

class Setor
{
    public $codigo;
    public $nome;
    protected $inputFilter;

    public function exchangeArray($data)
    {
        $this->codigo = (isset($data['codigo'])) ? $data['codigo'] : null;
        $this->nome = (isset($data['nome'])) ? $data['nome'] : null;
    }

    public function getInputFilter()
    {
        if (!$this->inputFilter) {
            $inputFilter = new InputFilter();
            $factory = new InputFactory();
            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                'name' => 'codigo',
                'required' => false,
                'filters' => array(
                    array('name' => 'ToInt'), ## It was Int, but in PHP 7 it not works anymore, so I replaced it as suggest the zend documentation https://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.4/classes/Zend.Filter.Int.html
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'Between',
                        'options' => array(
                            'min' => 0,
                            'max' => 3600
                        )
                    ),
                ),
            )));
            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                'name' => 'nome',
                'required' => true,
                'filters' => array(
                    array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'StringLength',
                        'options' => array(
                            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                            'min' => 2,
                            'max' => 30,
                        )
                    )
                ),
            )));
            $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;
        }

        return $this->inputFilter;
    }
}
```

When I run this class I get the message:

> Zend\Filter\FilterPluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an
>   instance for ToInt

Anybody knows how to validate Integers now that PHP 7 reserved the word Int?

Added:

After installing the zendframework/zend-filter version 2.7.1 the error message had changed to:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager::__construct() must
>   implement interface Zend\ServiceManager\ConfigInterface, instance of
>   Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\corps\vendor\zendframework\zend-filter\src\FilterChain.php
>   on line 112 and defined in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\corps\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager.php:60
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\corps\vendor\zendframework\zend-filter\src\FilterChain.php(112):
>   Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->__construct(Object(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager)) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\corps\vendor\zendframework\zend-filter\src\FilterChain.php(183):
>   Zend\Filter\FilterChain->getPluginManager() #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\corps\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\InputFilter\Factory.php(358):
>   Zend\Filter\FilterChain->attachByName('\Zend\Filter\To...', NULL,
>   1000) #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\corps\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\InputFilt
>   in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\corps\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager.php
>   on line 60

Comment: Which version of [zend-filter](https://packagist.org/packages/zendframework/zend-filter) do you have installed? (Run `composer show zendframework/zend-filter`.)

Comment: I ran the command and got the message "package zendframework/zend-filter not found"

Comment: When the problem has first appeared? Maybe you’ve somehow removed this package? On the other hand, `FilterPluginManager` belongs to this package as well, it wouldn’t be able to give you an error if not installed.

Comment: I was following a book, but the book was write before the release of php 7, so there was no problem with the Int filter before.

Comment: Does it work when you remove this filter? Can you try replacing `'ToInt'` with `\Zend\Filter\ToInt::class`? Does `composer show` output any filter/validator-related packages? In which versions? Do you run `composer` commands from the project’s root directory?

Comment: replacing to \Zend\Filter\ToInt::class does not work either, I tried to install zendframework/zend-filter, and now the error changed. I updated my answer with it.

Comment: and about the composer, I don't really have experience with it, so I dont know how to test those filter/validator-related that you've mentioned.

Comment: So perhaps you’re able to just post `composer show` output here? I guess your problem is related to these `zendframework` packages’ versions, but this command should judge it. And, please try running `composer update`.

Comment: when I run composer show I get the message:

zendframework/zendframework 2.3.1 Zend Framework 2
zendframework/zendxml 1.0.2 Utility library for xml usage,

Comment: It seems you’ve got zend-filter 2.3 installed? I think that you should start with upgrading all ZF packages to at least 2.4 (if you encounter problems, please share your `composer.json` contents). zend-filter 2.3 doesn’t contain `ToInt` filter (only old `Int`), but 2.4 does.

Comment: it worked! thank you! I just update to zf 2.4.11 and now it works. Funny that even Int filter now also works.

Comment: You’re welcome! I posted this solution as an actual answer so that it’ll be easier to find.

Comment: I marked it as the oficial solution! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you’ve got zend-filter 2.3 installed? I think that you should start upgrading all Zend Framework packages to at least 2.4 version. zend-filter 2.3 doesn’t contain `ToInt` filter, but 2.4 does. Both versions contain `Int` filter, but in 2.4 it only serves as a link to `ToInt` and additionally generates an error message (have a look at [`Int` class source in 2.4](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-filter/blob/release-2.4.0/src/Int.php)).